# The centrality that does not need to be named

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, terminology

Suppose we are looking at Internet domain names. Every country has its own two-letter abbreviation (.fr, .uk, .ca, .za, etc.) — except for the US, as far as I know. They have .com, .org, .edu, .gov. I assume there's an historic reason for this, but what I'm wondering is: is there a term to describe the assumed centrality of the US in the domain-name world — the country being so "central" that it does not even need to be identified. Only the *other* needs to be identified.

Now suppose we are in Europe or North America. I'm asked to describe a man. "He's five foot eight, brown hair, wearing a beige suit..." I know in North America and I presume in Europe, that unless I specifically state otherwise, he is assumed by most of my listeners to be white. In other words, *whiteness* like the US, is assumed to be so central that it does not need to be identified.

I could give many more examples of the margin vs. the centre, but hopefully these two illustrate what I mean.

*My Question:* Is there a term that describes this centrality — the centrality of not needing to be labelled, if you will?

I don't know how to research the question either on this site or elsewhere.

Comment: @Mahnax I'd edited out of my question that even if there is a .us domain name, I myself have never seen it, despite having visited thousands of US websites.

Comment: The classic term in linguistics is ['unmarked'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markedness)

Comment: you could call the US the default.

Comment: The only thing is that countless .com and .org domains are owned and operated by companies and institutions outside the US, such as this website in Dutch owned by the University of Leiden about the parliament of the Netherlands, http://www.parlement.com/ , and this random bar in Volendam: http://www.gatvannederland.com/ Etc. etc. So while .com may be mostly used by American organisations, and the US government rules over the domains (I believe), it is not exactly a US domain: it is used "by default" in other countries too, although less so than in the US.

Comment: I think this is Not Constructive. The specific examples (.com means American, and Americans/Europeans are white-skinned) are just *generalisations, preconceptions, parochialisms,* etc. The general term for "things which are assumed but not explicitly stated" is probably ***context***, but in OP's case I think I'd probably call his "centralities" ***prejudices***.

Comment: @StoneyB, does marked/unmarked tend to refer to groups of more than two (e.g. honest/dishonest)? Could it refer to The US vs. The Rest of the World?

Comment: @FumbleFingers oooh, can't resist another example: that Stack Exchange users are assumed to be male unless their ID specifically identifies them as otherwise... This OP's "centralities" are *her* centralities... :)

Comment: @JAM: Touché! I don't suppose it would do any good to say I was using it in the "gender-neutral" sense? Actually, it was a bad choice of words entirely. I didn't really mean to reinforce the idea that you personally make such assumptions, since they were just given as examples anyway. But the fact of the matter is we all make *lots* of assumptions about "shared knowledge/expectations" all the time, otherwise we'd never finish saying anything because of all the extra detail required. Whatever - StoneyB's **unmarked** is probably about the best you'll get here.

Comment: Well, Prague-school theory maintained that structure is defined by a series of binary contrasts. Us (or US) v Them, Ordinary Them v Exotic Them, Admirable Exotic Them v Contemptible Exotic Them, and so forth. My linguistics professor maintained that *mama* is virtually universal because its two components are the maximally-marked consonant and the minimally-marked vowel.

Comment: I should add that Prof. von Walburger-Engel spoke many languages fluently, but they were all European.

Comment: Incidentally, there is a .us domain, but it didn't become anywhere near as popular as some country TLDs.

Comment: @StoneyB could you please post 'unmarked' as an answer. I think it's the answer I'm looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for [**Americentrism**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americentrism).

> American networks are said to have an americentric bias in the selection of their material and U.S. celebrities have been accused of being **Americentric**.

I've also found [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exceptionalism) that you may be interested.

> **Exceptionalism** is the perception that a country, society, institution, movement, or time period is "exceptional" (i.e., unusual
>   or extraordinary) in some way and thus does not need to conform to
>   normal rules or general principles. Used in this sense, the term
>   reflects a belief formed by lived experience, ideology, perceptual
>   frames, or perspectives influenced by knowledge (or lack thereof) of
>   historical or comparative circumstances.

And to be more specific: **American exceptionalism**. Though [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Exceptionalism) suggests that

> **American exceptionalism** is the proposition that the United States is
>   different from other countries in that it has a specific world mission
>   to spread liberty and democracy.

it can be used to imply superiority:

> Although the term does not necessarily imply superiority, many
>   neoconservative and American conservative writers have promoted its
>   use in that sense. To them, the United States is like the
>   biblical "shining city on a hill," and exempt from historical forces
>   that have affected other countries.

Comment: This is interesting and explains why "National Novel Writing Month" is (supposedly) international. It's possible that there are two concepts at play which I unintentionally confounded in my question: the specific (American exceptionalism) and the more general, which might be described in StoneyB's marked/unmarked in the comments.

Comment: @JAM Yeah, both concepts are very similar.

Comment: I don't see this concept as being peculiar to America. After all, postage stamps are presumed to be British unless the name of the country is written on them.

Answer (score 0):

From the context, the appropriate adjective would be

> *[natural](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/natural)*
>   **2** of or in agreement with the character or makeup of, or circumstances surrounding, someone or something.

The top level domain name for the UK is naturally, .uk (as one would expect).
The people of Spain, naturally, speak Spanish -- what else?

Comment: Really, one would expect the TLD for the UK to be .gb because usually they use ISO 3166 codes (and .gb does indeed also exist). .uk is an historical accident which may or may not involve people from Queens University Belfast expressing a preference to Jon Postel, depending on which sources you believe.

Answer (score 0):

.com is a prototypical domain suffix, and a white man is the prototype of an American man.

> prototype
>   n 1: a standard or typical example; "he is the prototype of good breeding"; "he provided America with an image of the good father" [syn: prototype, paradigm, epitome, image]
>   — WordNet (r) 3.0 (2006)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the assumption of certain default characteristics reflects the [*hegemony*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/hegemony) of particular groups within that domain (Weak pun intended).